# Subclass doesn't have visibility to abstract base class member variable

Tags: apex

I'm trying to create a subclass of `BaseClass` (`SecondClass`). `SecondClass` is extending `BaseClass`.

`BaseClass` is a abstract class, which has a member variable `sList`.

Since I am extending BaseClass in my SecondClass, I guess we can use sList  here in SecondClass.

But when I am saving the SecondClass, I am gating

> Saving Error : member variable not visible for assignment

Any Idea?

```
public with sharing class SecondClass extends BaseClass {

   private void init() {

         //this.sList = new SelectorList();
   }


}



public abstract class BaseClass {

   public SelectorList sList {get; private set;}

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `private` access modifier on your setter in your base class.

> `private`
>   This is the default, and means that the method or variable is accessible **only within the Apex class in which it is defined**. If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is `private`.

You need to use `protected` or `public` on your setter to be able to call it in a subclass.

> `protected`
>   This means that the method or variable is visible to any inner classes in the defining Apex class, and to the **classes that extend the defining Apex class**. You can only use this access modifier for instance methods and member variables. Note that it is strictly more permissive than the default (`private`) setting, just like Java.
>
> `public`
>   This means the method or variable can be used by **any Apex in this application or namespace**.

Documentation on Access Modifiers can be found [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm).