# VF Error "unknown property" : base and extended controllerExtension classes

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a fake many to many relationship between Contact and itself which is used to maintain a history of old contacts which are used to create new contacts. I created a custom object `ContactHistory__c` with two lookup relationships to `Contact`. I did this because it is not possible to have two master-detail relationships between the same two objects. Yes, it is hackish, but it works around the Salesforce limitation and it actually works fine.

The only issue is the related lists in `Contact` are ugly: they point to the junction object, not the other contacts. To address this issue, I decided to create an inline VisualForce page with a custom controller which does the (not so) heavy lifting of looking up the target contacts.

However, I receive a save error "unknown property `ContactStandardController.related`" It appears that it is not finding the `related` property on the custom controller because it is looking at the standard controller. This is not even wired into a page layout yet, I am still writing the functionality. I understand that for this to work it must use the standard Contact controller with an extension, since this will be inline in the standard Contact page.

Abstract controller (there will be two concrete classes for new/old contacts):

```
public abstract class AbstractRelatedContactsController {

  private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
  private Contact c {get; private set;}
  private List<Contact> related {get; private set;}

  public AbstractRelatedContactsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    controller = stdController;
    c = (Contact) controller.getRecord();
    related = lookup(c);
  }

  protected List<Contact> lookup(Contact current) {
    Set<Id> ids = getIds(current);
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :ids];
  }

  protected abstract Set<Id> getIds(Contact current);
}
```

Concrete controller:

```
public class NewContactsController
    extends AbstractRelatedContactsController {

  public NewContactsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    super(stdController);
  }

  protected override Set<Id> getIds(Contact current) {
    Set<Id> oldIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (ContactHistory__c ch : [SELECT NewContact__c FROM ContactHistory__c WHERE OldContact__c = :current.Id]) {
      oldIds.add(ch.NewContact__c);
    }
    return oldIds;
  }
}
```

VisualForce:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="NewContactsController">
  <apex:pageBlock title="New Contacts">
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <!--apex:commandButton TODO /-->
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!related}" var="c"><!-- ERROR IS CAUSED BY THIS LINE -->
        <apex:column headerValue="Contact">
          <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.Id}">{!c.Id} {!c.Name}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

How do I fix this error and get this working?

Comment: In AbstractRelatedContactsController, can you change 'private related' to 'public related' and retry?

Comment: John, I'd like to second the comment from user320. What happens if you change the visibility of `related` from private to **public**?

Comment: There was a great answer to similar issue recently here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33941/subclass-doesnt-have-visibility-to-abstract-base-class-member-variable

Comment: That worked, thanks. It was the same issue as the other question. Due to where I was getting the error, my searches did not find that question. This had nothing to do with the subclass (it was not modifying any state) and everything to do with the VF page not being able to see the property. That itself was also misleading, because the error it reported was that the property was not on the _standard_ controller, leading me to believe that my custom controller was not being used.

Comment: Someone make an answer that explains this and I will accept it. I would rather give the rep to someone else rather than it going to /dev/null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this was a visibility issue.

The reason is that access to a member goes through the accessor, not directly to the field. So regardless of the visibility of the field, if the setter is private, the subclass cannot set its value.